# Emberjs - Why view.element is undefined

Tags: ember.js

Guys,

I am new to Emberjs, now trying Ember 1.0.0 out.

But I am confused that when I create a new View, and then append it to `body`, and in `didInsertElement`, `view.element` returns `undefined` which I expect to be an element.

I went a little bit into the source code, and try using `view.currentState.getElement(view)`, and it returns the element correctly.

Why is that? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the element from this object like this,

```
didInsertElement: function() {
   console.log(this.get('element')); //logs the element
}
```